# How to Connect Kentico Website with database

Tags: asp.net, kentico

I just started working with Kentico and after Kentico Installation there is no setup files for my sql server database but I get the files are locally stored in the database(on localdb). So now I want to know that how can I connect with the existing database(sql server). As I try to change the web config but there are issue when we run the service from Kentico Service Manager.

Also I am having an another issue that how can this be possible with kentico that if the admin made certain changes in the text through interface and those changes should be reflected in database as well.So that next time when anybody tries to access the website it will reflect to him. Please let me know about it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please, refer: 
 [Connecting your project to the database](https://kentico.atlassian.net/wiki/display/KPLUS/Connecting+to+the+database)

[Daabase Setup](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/6_0/azureguide/index.html?database_setup.htm)

```
Managed projects are connected to the database and contain Kentico EMS data by default.
If you're using an unmanaged project, you must connect the project to the database manually. You have two options to connect your project to the database:
entering the database credentials into the database setup wizard
adding a connection string to your application's web.config
Connection string template

    <add name="CMSConnectionString" connectionString="Persist Security 
Info=False;database=DATABASE_NAME;server=SERVER_NAME;user 
id=USER_NAME;password=PASSWORD;Current Language=English;Connection Timeout=240;"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now I just want to know that how can this be possible with Kentico that if I made some changes in the project then those changes must be saved in the database. Let me know is you understand my query or not.

Comment: It would be good if you could clarify the issue with saving data or updating document info.